# python: How to debug multiprocess? (using eclipse+pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, multiprocess

I've seen a couple of questions on the topic but I didn't get a full answer...

My code is basically:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=f).start()
p.join()

def f():
  print 'break!'
```

And I want to put a breakpoint on the `print`. I'm using pydev+eclipse (on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the new process itself is not controlled by PyDev, you need to make PyDev debugger manually aware of through Remote Debugging facilities.

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Use pydevd.set_trace() - notice that your breakpoints won't work (not sure if this has changed recent PyDev versions), but you need to manually enter set_trace() command to your code.

Comment: it's `settrace()` and not `set_trace()` and I had to set the port manually (i.e., `pydevd.settrace(port=xx)`). Other than that, it works great, thanks!